# .htaccess: How to 301 redirect content from domainA.com/folderA/ to domainB.com/folderB?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Newbie here - this puzzle's had me racking my brains for hours now. Basically, as the title alludes to, I'm in the process of transferring content from one domain to another, as well as to a slightly different folder configuration. Essentially, I'm in need of the necessary .htaccess code that will allow me to redirect visitors attempting to access files situated within domainA.com/folderA/ to domainB.com/folderB

So, if a visitor were to visit...

http://domainA.com/folderA/page1.html

... they would be immediately transferred to...

http://domainB.com/folderB/page1.html

If anyone can help me out, I would be very much grateful. Thanks a bunch for looking into my likely-very-straightforward-but-still-head-scratching quandary!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If domainA and domainB are hosted on different servers, you can simply add an htaccess file in `folderA` that says:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domainB.com/folderB/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Or in domainA's document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^folderA/(.*)$ http://domainB.com/folderB/$1 [L,R=301]
```

If both domains are served by the same document root, you need to check against the hostname:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainA\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domainB.com/folderB/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Or in domainA's document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainA\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^folderA/(.*)$ http://domainB.com/folderB/$1 [L,R=301]
```